# FTP inbound connector in Mule don't have auto Delete Option enabled

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a requirement like, inbound as FTP component. I need to process the file in FTP connector and at the same time I shouldn't delete the file until the file get completely processed.

Currently file is being deleted as soon as it is consumed.

```
<ftp:connector  name="FTPCommonConnector"  pollingFrequency="10000"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="FTP"> </ftp:connector>
```

I'm trying to accommodate the delFile option. It is throwing error as below. Why delFile functionality is not enabled in FTP?.Is there any other way I can achieve this. Please help.

```
 <ftp:connector delFiles="false"   name="FTPCommonConnector"  pollingFrequency="10000"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="FTP"> </ftp:connector>
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'delFiles' is not allowed to appear in element 'ftp:connector'.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a global configuration element. At the advanced tab you can choose the option 'Delete files after processing'.

Comment: I don't want to delete the file till the file is being successfully processed. I can delete it externally. I have tried the option you mentioned. For not to delete the file, need to use the option `move to Pattern`  `<ftp:connector name="FTP" connectionTimeout="40000" pollingFrequency="1000" validateConnections="true" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" doc:name="FTP"></ftp:connector>`. But it is giving error like below. Is it the problem with jar version. I'm not sure. Need the help, please suggest.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename file datas.csv to datas.csv. Ftp error: 550
 at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.ftp.EEFtpMessageReceiver.postProcess(EEFtpMessageReceiver.java:66) ~[mule-transport-ftp-ee-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2].

Comment: Actaullay i dont want to rename by file and Move to different directory. I just want  when my flow is taken the file for processing, it need not delete the file from FTP. I can delete it externally. But the option in FTP connectors gives in either need to choose `Move to Pattern` or `move to Directory`.  Even after using `move to Pattern` it is throwing error. Hope my point is understanding.

Comment: Might help others. `MoveTo Directory` always pointing RemoteDiercetory. If you want to keep the file in FTP. Use  `MoveTo Directory=" yourSamePath"` and "move to pattern =#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]". It is keep the file in FTP without deleteing with the same name.